# How do you find the $p(x)$ and $E(x^2)$ of this table?

Tags: statistics

How do you find the $p(x)$, $E(x^2)$ and variance of this table?

\begin{array}{c|cccc}
x & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2\\\hline
p(x) & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.1 & ?
\end{array}
[Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI4KJ.png)

How do I find $p(x)=?$, $E(x^2)=?$ and variance $σ^2 = ?$ in the table?

answer is: $p(x) = 0.6$, $E(x^2) = 2.6$ and $σ^2 = 1.16$

Comment: Do you understand the properties of probability mass function, and expected value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distribution table must satisfy 
$$\sum_x p(x) = 1.$$

The expectation is
$$E[X]  = \sum_x xp(x).$$
Finally, 
$$E[X^2] = \sum_x x^2p(x),$$
and
$$\text{Var}(X) = E[X^2]-\{E[X]\}^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $-1,0,1,2$ are the only possible outcomes $P(x=2)= 1-.4=.6$

$E(x^2) = \sum x^2P(x) = 1*.1+1*.1+4*.6=2.6$